# Cannot click Publish button in Sitecore

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am not able to click Publish button in Sitecore. It shows unable to locate element.
I used below `xpath` expressions but they not worked:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='NextButton']")).click(); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[2]/div[2]/button[2]")).click();
```

Please refer screenshot for more details.
[image]

Comment: Did you add the right tags? I also found a nice [Querying Items from Sitecore](http://sitecoreworld.blogspot.nl/2014/09/querying-items-from-sitecore.html) article.

Comment: I think added tags correct.

Answer (score 2):

It seem that you need to switch to `iframe`, wait until `Publish item` modal window opens and until `Publish` button is clickable... Try below code and let me know the result:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
```

switch to `iframe`

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("scContentIframeId0"));
```

or

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By .id("scContentIframeId0")));
driver.switchTo().frame("scContentIframeId0");
```

click "Publish"

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("NextButton"))).click();
```

Comment: Did not worked...How to establish that Selenium is actually recognising Modal Window or not?

Comment: Can you check whether your modal located inside an `iframe`?

Comment: Can you share `HTML` of  `iframe`?

Comment: <iframe id="scContentIframeId0" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content ui-dialog-normal" src="/sitecore/shell/Applications/Publish.aspx?id=%7B1AF6B777-7CD6-4445-A776-BF8BDF4D695C%7D" style="width: auto; min-height: 0px; max-height: none; height: 600px;"></iframe>

Comment: Try to add `driver.switchTo().frame("scContentIframeId0"); ` before clicking button

Comment: Not worked: Showed error No frame element found by name or id scContentIframeId0

Comment: Updated. Check it again

Comment: Timed Out waiting for Frame to be available

Comment: I don't get it... Let's make it clear. You make click to open modal, then you're waiting for `iframe` to switch to it, then wait for "Publish" button to click it, right?

Comment: i make click to open the "Publish Item" window. In this window I had to click Publish Button.Please see screenshot.

Comment: Yes. This is obvious :) I want to know little more details. After you click *something* "Publish Item" window opens and you use my code to switch to `iframe` with `id="scContentIframeId0"` and then click "Publish", right? This is the exact sequence of your actions?

Comment: Exactly. This is sequence

Comment: Can you doublecheck whether `iframe` `id` is static and it's always `"scContentIframeId0"`? Also try to replace `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("scContentIframeId0")); ` with `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By
                .id("scContentIframeId0")));`

Comment: It is same everytime. Can we confirm that we have moved to desired iframe... like getcurrenturl etc. helps to get current url.... in same any function to extract current frame id and print it . I used with index like driver.switchTo().frame(1); it showed error on clicking publish button but not on recognizing frame

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37791547/selenium-webdriver-get-current-frame-before-switch

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32283337/selenium-is-unable-to-find-element-in-a-modal-window-with-iframes

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript Executor like below,

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("abcd"));
JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jsExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: Did not Worked. Unable to locate element.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same scenario: click publish button using selenium.

1)    In Ruby, there is a gem called pageobject called PageObject.

In it, there's a method called in_iframe. It is used to select elements in the iframe. Check out this code snippet:

```
class RegistrationPage
  include PageObject

  in_frame(:id => 'left-frame') do |outer_frame|
    in_frame({:id => 'left-top-frame'}, outer_frame) do |inner_frame|
      text_field(:address, :id => 'address_id', :frame => inner_frame)
    end
  end
end
```

2)    As for the publish button, I inspected the element and I found that the publish button is in nested iframe:
[image]

Do check if your code is handling elements in nested iframe

cheers